# Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Invalid persistence.xml. Cannot find the declaration of element 'persistence'

Tags: jboss7.x, java-ee-6, ejb-3.1, persistence.xml, hibernate-entitymanager

I am currently working on an Enterprise Application and I am having problems setting up the entitymanagerfactory. I keep getting this message.

```
10:26:37,661 ERROR [org.jboss.ejb3.invocation] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component LoginBean for method public abstract java.lang.Boolean com.fe10a096ejb.beans.remote.LoginBeanRemote.isLoggedIn(): javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS011048: Failed to construct component instance
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:166) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:230) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:304) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:190) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.EJBRemoteTransactionPropagatingInterceptor.processInvocation(EJBRemoteTransactionPropagatingInterceptor.java:80) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:32) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.LocalEjbReceiver.processInvocation(LocalEjbReceiver.java:179) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:179) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.TransactionInterceptor.handleInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:43) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:181) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.ReceiverInterceptor.handleInvocation(ReceiverInterceptor.java:128) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:181) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:136) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:121) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:104) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.isLoggedIn(Unknown Source)
    at com.fe10a096.web.servlets.Login.doGet(Login.java:36)
    at com.fe10a096.web.servlets.Login.doPost(Login.java:67)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
    at org.jboss.modcluster.container.jbossweb.JBossWebContext$RequestListenerValve.event(JBossWebContext.java:67)
    at org.jboss.modcluster.container.jbossweb.JBossWebContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(JBossWebContext.java:48)
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS011048: Failed to construct component instance
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:163) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.createInstance(BasicComponent.java:85) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.stateless.StatelessSessionComponent$1.create(StatelessSessionComponent.java:66) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.stateless.StatelessSessionComponent$1.create(StatelessSessionComponent.java:63) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.pool.AbstractPool.create(AbstractPool.java:60) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.pool.strictmax.StrictMaxPool.get(StrictMaxPool.java:123) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:47) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:228) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to invoke constructor
    at org.jboss.msc.value.ConstructedValue.getValue(ConstructedValue.java:65)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.ValueManagedReferenceFactory.getReference(ValueManagedReferenceFactory.java:49)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory.java:90) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:161) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 54 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at org.jboss.msc.value.ConstructedValue.getValue(ConstructedValue.java:61)
    ... 67 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Invalid persistence.xml.
Error parsing XML (line-1 : column -1): cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'persistence'.

    at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.PersistenceXmlLoader.loadURL(PersistenceXmlLoader.java:145) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.PersistenceXmlLoader.deploy(PersistenceXmlLoader.java:169) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:323) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:55) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63) [hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar:1.0.1.Final]
    at com.fe10a096ejb.persistence.MyPersistence.(MyPersistence.java:42) [fe10a096ejb.jar:]
    at com.fe10a096ejb.beans.impl.LoginBean.(LoginBean.java:34) [fe10a096ejb.jar:]
    ... 72 more

10:26:38,903 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/fe10a096web].[com.fe10a096.web.servlets.Login]] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) Servlet.service() for servlet com.fe10a096.web.servlets.Login threw exception: javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS011048: Failed to construct component instance
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:166) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:230) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:304) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:190) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.EJBRemoteTransactionPropagatingInterceptor.processInvocation(EJBRemoteTransactionPropagatingInterceptor.java:80) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:32) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.LocalEjbReceiver.processInvocation(LocalEjbReceiver.java:179) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:179) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.TransactionInterceptor.handleInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:43) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:181) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.ReceiverInterceptor.handleInvocation(ReceiverInterceptor.java:128) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:181) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:136) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:121) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:104) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.isLoggedIn(Unknown Source)
    at com.fe10a096.web.servlets.Login.doGet(Login.java:36) [classes:]
    at com.fe10a096.web.servlets.Login.doPost(Login.java:67) [classes:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.modcluster.container.jbossweb.JBossWebContext$RequestListenerValve.event(JBossWebContext.java:67)
    at org.jboss.modcluster.container.jbossweb.JBossWebContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(JBossWebContext.java:48)
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS011048: Failed to construct component instance
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:163) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.createInstance(BasicComponent.java:85) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.stateless.StatelessSessionComponent$1.create(StatelessSessionComponent.java:66) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.stateless.StatelessSessionComponent$1.create(StatelessSessionComponent.java:63) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.pool.AbstractPool.create(AbstractPool.java:60) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.pool.strictmax.StrictMaxPool.get(StrictMaxPool.java:123) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:47) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:228) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to invoke constructor
    at org.jboss.msc.value.ConstructedValue.getValue(ConstructedValue.java:65)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.ValueManagedReferenceFactory.getReference(ValueManagedReferenceFactory.java:49)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory.java:90) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:161) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 54 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at org.jboss.msc.value.ConstructedValue.getValue(ConstructedValue.java:61)
    ... 67 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Invalid persistence.xml.
Error parsing XML (line-1 : column -1): cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'persistence'.

    at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.PersistenceXmlLoader.loadURL(PersistenceXmlLoader.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.PersistenceXmlLoader.deploy(PersistenceXmlLoader.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:323)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:55)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63) [hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar:1.0.1.Final]
    at com.fe10a096ejb.persistence.MyPersistence.(MyPersistence.java:42)
    at com.fe10a096ejb.beans.impl.LoginBean.(LoginBean.java:34)
    ... 72 more
```

I have been on it for days! Help please!!!
This is my persitence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="htttp://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocaion="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="Cef502PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="url"/>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect"  value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="pwd"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="none" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Ad this is my directory structure
[image]

Comment: This is actually an end of course project and time is not on my side. Help please!!!

Comment: Review|Help and Improvement: formatted

Answer (score 0):

Ah! I finally saw where my problem was. Here is my solution as directed in the JBOSS 7 developers' guide (JBoss AS 7.1) page 39

1. I created a directory JBOSS_HOME/modules/com/mysql/main
2. Then placed the mysql connectory mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar inside
3. Then created a file named module.xml in the same directory with the content

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.mysql">
  <resources>
     <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
     <module name="javax.api"/>
   </dependencies>
</module>
```

4. I then created a driver entry in the  tag for this module in the file JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml as shown

```html
<driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
   <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
</driver>
```

5. Now I was free to create a datasource from this driver by adding a new datasource in the  tag in the same file as shown

```html
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/mydb" pool-name="my_pool" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
  <connection-url>db-url</connection-url>
  <driver>mysql</driver>
  <security>
    <user-name>username</user-name>
    <password>password</password>
  </security>
  <statement>
    <prepared-statement-cache-size>100</prepared-statement-cache-size>
    <share-prepared-statements>true</share-prepared-statements>
  </statement>
</datasource>
```

6. Take note that the driver tag in the datasource entry corresponds to the driver name in the driver tag inside the  tag. This was my mistake.
7. Now you can refer to the datasource you just created from you Beans using its name. For example to get an entity manager form it, simple add the field

```html
@PersistenceContext(unitName="persitent_unit_name")
EntityManager em;
```

8. Done!